# passport.js not working with nestjs (fastify)

Tags: passport.js, nestjs, fastify

I am using fastifyAdapter instead of expressAdapter on nestjs.
it gives me following error-

```
TypeError: res.setHeader is not a function
at GoogleStrategy.strategy.redirect
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, Fastify is [*not* compatible with *passport.js*](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/2100#issuecomment-487408042) Nest.js module

`fastify` has different redirect and functions in general from express, so not all middlewares are compatible: see for example [redirect differences](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/performance#redirect-response) from docs